# Checking user exists in a trusted AD domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am running code from domain DOMAIN1. There is a one way trust set up with DOMAIN2. I wish to validate if a user in DOMAIN2 exists. When I try I get an exception saying 'invalid username and password'. I take it I have to supply credentials to a user that exists in DOMAIN2 to allow the search, but how can I do this? and how can I fix it so that authentication is not needed (two way trust?)

```
      try
      {
           //this works find for a user in the current domain
          PrincipalContext ctx1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN1");
          UserPrincipal user1 = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx1, "user1");
          GroupPrincipal group1 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx1, "group1");
          bool ue1 = user1.IsMemberOf(group1);


//this fails with invalid username/password but is a trusted domain
          PrincipalContext ctx2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN2");
          UserPrincipal user2 = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx2, "user2");
          GroupPrincipal group2 = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx2, "group2");
          bool ue2 = user2.IsMemberOf(group2);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          string ex;
          ex = e.Message;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PrincipalContext constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts a username and password.

```
PrincipalContext ctx1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN1", "username", "password");
```

If you don't want to pass credentials, then your application needs to be running under credentials that are trusted by both domains.

So if DOMAIN1 trusts DOMAIN2, then your application should run under credentials on DOMAIN2.

If DOMAIN2 trusts DOMAIN1, then your application should run under credentials on DOMAIN1.

If you cannot do that, then, yes, a two-way trust would solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But is there a way to do this without requiring authentication, i.e. checking DOMAIN1 from DOMAIN1 works fine and I don't really want to have to supply credentials for DOMAIN2. Is there something that can be set up on the AD to allow this?

Comment: You said there's a one-way trust. Which way is it? Does DOMAIN1 trust DOMAIN2, or does DOMAIN2 trust DOMAIN1?